# How to parse email and passwords from text file (Python)

Tags: python, parsing

how would I go about extracting emails and passwords from a text file in the format of email:pass ? I would like to attribute email to a variable, and password to a variable as well.

Comment: How is the text file structured?

Comment: Its in the question. email:pass, then a new line, with another email:pass, until the end of the txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the text file has the form of-

```
email:password
email:password
email:password
```

and so on, here's how you could extract each piece

```
afile = open("yourfile.txt", "r')
for line in afile:
    pieces = line.split(":")
    email = pieces[0]
    password = pieces[1]
    #do whatever else you need to with each email and password here>
```

You'll have to make sure that your Python file is in the same directory as the .txt file for this to run correctly as-is (replacing "yourfile.txt" with your actual filename, of course). The only thing to watch out for is if an email address could have a ":" in it. If it does, for example "abc:def@email.com", then "abc" would get set as the email and "def@email.com" would get set as the password. If emails can include colons, then you'd have a bit more work to better split each line. But if they don't include colons, you're set.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I get Index Error: list index out of range when running this though

Comment: You can debug by printing out the variable pieces before indexing to get the email and password. That indicates that there's a line that doesn't get correctly split

Answer (score 0):

You're first going to need to figure out how the text file is formatted. If there is different emails on each line then you can use this resource to read each line [Read Lines in Python.](http://cmdlinetips.com/2011/08/three-ways-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-python/) Once you are able to read the file lines, you need to use string manipulation to get the variables you need

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file like:

```
email1:password1
email2:password2:
email3:password3
```

Then you can create a dictionary using:

```
emails = {email : password for email, password in map( lambda x:x.split(':'), open('file.txt', 'r').readlines() )}
```

This will allow you to call password values using the email string:

```
emails['email1']
password1
```